# JavaFX - disappearing icons on toolbar buttons

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm writing JavaFX  application on JDK 8. The application has a menu and toolbar with some buttons. The problem is, when ever menu opens and covers toolbar buttons, icons on tollbar buttons disappear. Button functionality  remains unchanged, tooltips appear correctly, only icons are missing. The image bellow shows this:

[image]

I create toolbar buttons off the UI thread, but add them to the toolbar on UI thread.

```
 // this is off UI thread
 newFileButton = new Button();
 newFileButton.setId(JFXFileMenuConstants.NEW_FILE_TOOLBAR_BUTTON);
 newFileButton.setGraphic((Node) handler.getResource("jfx.gui.file.new.menuitem.icon"));
    newFileButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(handler.getString("jfx.gui.toolbar.newfile.tooltip")));
 .........
   ToolBar filesToolbar = new ToolBar(newFileButton, openFileButton, separator, saveFileButton, saveasFileButton);

  Platform.runLater(() -> {
        toolbarContainer.getChildren().add(toolbar);
    });
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: What happens if u execute the whole code on Application Thread?

Comment: no idea without a SSCCCE (small runnable example) that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I can't execute whole code at once, since this is OSGI module, which is part of larger application. Toolbar is actually added in another OSGI bundle.
Same thing for SSCCCE, I can't provide it since the rest of the code is in the other OSGI bundle

Comment: You are not able to see the graphics coz the code that should be in the UI thread is off it. Setting graphics to a button is also a part of JavaFX application and should be done within the JavaFX application thread.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer my own question, the problem was in resource loading. I was loading icons as an `ImageView`, instead of `Image`. In resource bundle, I had

```
 {"jfx.gui.file.new.menuitem.icon", new ImageView(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/icons/filenew.png").toString()) },
```

When I changed this to

```
 {"jfx.gui.file.new.menuitem.icon", new Image(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/icons/filenew.png").toString()) },
```

and  this line:

```
newFileButton.setGraphic((Node) handler.getResource("jfx.gui.file.new.menuitem.icon"));
```

to

```
newFileButton.setGraphic(new ImageView((Image)handler.getResource("jfx.gui.file.new.menuitem.icon")));
```

everything worked.
Thanks a lot to everybody for your suggestions.

Comment: To explain what was happened: You can only add a Node once to the SceneGraph. ImageView is a node and apparently you tried to add it twice (Menu + ToolBar) to the SceneGraph. Using Image and creating ImageViews of it prevents this.

Comment: @eckig you are right, that is exactly what happened. Will know better next time :-)